# Can't get html from url with Python

Tags: python, html, urllib

Can some tell me why my urlopen method is all of a sudden not working

```
import urllib


url = "http://www.google.com"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(page)
```

Comment: You need to actually import `urllib.request`

Comment: 'not working' is a pretty wide description. You might wanna attach some specifics, like stack traces, logs, error description, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should import **urllib.request** not just **urllib**;
2. which version do you use, this code only work in python3.X, see this https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request for detail;
3. If it did have exception, it may encounter network problem, make sure you can reach "google.com"(try it with browser or whatever)